# What is the scheme for google+?

Tags: mobile, google-plus

I am searching for the scheme of google+, so i can create a link which starts the Google+ app.

Twitter (`twitter://user?screen_name=XYZ`) and Facebook (`fb://profile/ID`) are working but i can't find one for Google+.

`plus://` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the scheme now. It's `gplus://`. But now i need a parameter like user or profile to select a profile after starting the app. Someone out there who can help?